# Why can't I list all helm releases, if I have no permissions for other instances, such as secrets?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using helm cli v3.11.0 and trying to execute `helm list`. For some reason, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: list: failed to list: secrets is forbidden: User "developer" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace
```

although I did not ask for any secrets :)

Is there a way to list helm releases without asking for instances I have no permissions for?

Comment: Helm now saves all revision histories as secrets in K8s so you need to get access to Secrets if you want to see history.

Answer (score 0):

Helm normally [stores its state in Secret objects](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends), so the history of what's been installed with what values lives in Secrets.  With a normal setup, the user running `helm` commands needs RBAC permissions to read and write Secrets in the target namespace.  This shouldn't normally be an issue since a chart will very frequently contain a Secret and the act of installing a chart will necessarily create new resources in the cluster.

`helm list` may only require "get" and "list" permissions on Secrets, but you will need some permissions.  You can't read the state stored in the cluster without having permission on it.

The linked documentation notes that it's possible to store the state in other places, like a ConfigMap or an SQL database.  You'd still need permission to read the ConfigMap or credentials on the database.  The documentation also notes that the Helm state contains the entire input to the Helm chart – there is enough information to `helm get values` – and this can include things like passwords and other credentials; so if you intentionally don't have permission to read back Secrets you probably also shouldn't have permission to read Helm values, and therefore the Helm state.